# Upgrade R package on ec2 instance

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, amazon-ec2, r

The version of R is 3.4 and want to upgrade it to 3.6. Then I have followed the these steps:

1. `sudo /bin/bash`
   and I just went to root.

Then remove the r-base core:

2. `# apt-get remove r-base-core`

and here is the result:

```
Package 'r-base-core' is not installed, so not removed
```

3. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/"`

Then add the public key:

4. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`

After that:

5. `apt-get update`
6. `apt-get upgrade`

And finally

7. `apt-get install r-base`

   However here is the error that I got:

   ```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.2-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.2-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

I tried to install 3.6.2-1bionic separately and it does not work. 
Could you please let me know how I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and worked for me: 
I just commented the previous repository in  source list as follows:

```
$sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment previous version of R

```
# deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

and add the new version repository:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

Then add public key :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

and finally update and instal r-base
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```